# picamera incorrect buffer length

Tags: python, picamera, raspberry-pi-desktop

I am currently using a pi camera module to stream video using flask and at some point, it randomly crashes. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40065328/picameravalueerror-incorrect-buffer-length-for-resolution-1920x1080)  over here and they say that clearing the stream helped them sort this out, but in my case, it doesn't seem to work.

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1704, in capture_continuous
    'Timed out waiting for capture to end')
picamera.exc.PiCameraRuntimeError: Timed out waiting for capture to end

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/secure-pi-tensorflow/securepi/pivideostream.py", line 39, in update
    for f in self.stream:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 1710, in capture_continuous
    encoder.close()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 431, in close
    self.stop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 419, in stop
    self._close_output()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/encoders.py", line 349, in _close_output
    mo.close_stream(output, opened)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/mmalobj.py", line 371, in close_stream
    stream.flush()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 238, in flush
    self.array = bytes_to_rgb(self.getvalue(), self.size or self.camera.resolution)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/picamera/array.py", line 127, in bytes_to_rgb
    'Incorrect buffer length for resolution %dx%d' % (width, height))
picamera.exc.PiCameraValueError: Incorrect buffer length for resolution 1920x1080
```

this is the code that I am currently using and as said above I clear the stream but I still get the error.

```
# import the necessary packages
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
from threading import Thread
import cv2

class PiVideoStream:
    def __init__(self, resolution=(320, 240), framerate=32, **kwargs):
        # initialize the camera
        self.camera = PiCamera()

        # set camera parameters
        self.camera.resolution = resolution
        self.camera.framerate = framerate

        # set optional camera parameters (refer to PiCamera docs)
        for (arg, value) in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self.camera, arg, value)

        # initialize the stream
        self.rawCapture = PiRGBArray(self.camera, size=resolution)
        self.stream = self.camera.capture_continuous(self.rawCapture,
            format="bgr", use_video_port=True)

        # initialize the frame and the variable used to indicate
        # if the thread should be stopped
        self.frame = None
        self.stopped = False

    def start(self):
        # start the thread to read frames from the video stream
        t = Thread(target=self.update, args=())
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        return self

    def update(self):
        # keep looping infinitely until the thread is stopped
        for f in self.stream:
            # grab the frame from the stream and clear the stream in
            # preparation for the next frame
            self.frame = f.array
            self.rawCapture.truncate(0)
            self.rawCapture.seek(0)

            # if the thread indicator variable is set, stop the thread
            # and resource camera resources
            if self.stopped:
                self.stream.close()
                self.rawCapture.close()
                self.camera.close()
                return

    def read(self):
        # return the frame most recently read
        return self.frame

    def stop(self):
        # indicate that the thread should be stopped
        self.stopped = True
```